# What does Change password if the user is signed in with Google or Facebook

Tags: firebase-authentication

Suppose that a user is signed in with Facebook or Google using Firebase auth.  What does it mean to change user password since there is no password to change in the first place?

I appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Firebase Authentication account can have an associated password, no matter what provider the user initially signed in with.

Calling Firebase's `updatePassword` API [sets that password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#set_a_users_password). If the user was signed in with another provider, the password on that provider will not be changed by calling Firebase's `updatePassword` API.

Comment: I also noticed that when ever I sign up with Facebook or Google for the first time, then I update the password, a new email-password provider is added to the account. So that is what it is. Thanks for your help.